# I have a problem on API Resources Laravel (Maximum stack depth exceeded)

Tags: php, laravel, web, backend

i have a problem when i use API Resources inside another API Resources class like this:

```
if (! Route::is('job.*')) {
            $data['sites']= SiteResource::collection($this->sites);
           $data['jobs'] =  JobResource::collection($this->jobs);
 }
```

but when I remove the class the problem disappears like this :

```
 if (! Route::is('job.*')) {
                $data['sites']= $this->sites;
               $data['jobs'] =  $this->jobs;
     }
```

this is -> image for error

[image: 1]

this is my code :

```
class CustomerResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {

        $data = [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'billing_details' => $this->billing_details,
            'billing_info' => [
                'address' => $this->billing->address,
                'street_num' =>$this->billing->street_num,
                'country' =>$this->billing->country->name,
                'city' =>$this->billing->city,
                'postal_code' =>$this->billing->postal_code,
                'credit_limit' =>$this->billing->credit_limit,
                'payment_term_id' =>$this->billing->payment_term_id,
                'send_statement'  =>$this->billing->send_statement
            ],
           'contacts' => $this->contacts,
            'sitecontact' => $this->sitecontact,

        ];


        if (! Route::is('job.*')) {
            $data['sites']= SiteResource::collection($this->sites);
           $data['jobs'] =  JobResource::collection($this->jobs);
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in SiteResource::class and JobRessource:class that will lead to an infinite loop between them ?

Comment: @N69S
I called customerRessource class on  JobRessource class 
I fixed it 
 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I called CustomerRessource class on JobRessource class which leads to an infinite loop between them

[JobRessource class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzjhz.png)

```
if (! Route::is('job.*')) {
      $data['sites']= SiteResource::collection($this->sites);
      $data['jobs'] =  JobResource::collection($this->jobs);
   }
```

I fixed it by using this condition on JobRessource

```
  if (Route::is('job.*')) {
       $data['customer' ] = new CustomerResource($this->customer);
   }
```

[JobRessource with condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFcrG.png)

@N69S thank you for your comment

Comment: What is "this condition"?  Please share all details, like the code involved and an explanation, in text form

Comment: @NicoHaase I added an image to my answer and the condition is in the image

Comment: If that image contains code, please share the code **in text form**. That's the best way to share textual content